# Rotate image around circumference right-side-up

Tags: css, rotation

I'm placing images around the circumference of a circle using CSS3. These images will be at variable degrees around the circumference like 91d, 120d, 240d, etc. So far I can only figure out how to keep the images right side up like this:

```
CSS:

@keyframes rot {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
               translate(-150px)
               rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(-180deg)
               translate(-150px) 
               rotate(180deg);
    }
 }

.smile {
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: 110px;
left: 50%;
border-radius: 20px;
margin: -20px;
font-size: 100px;
animation: rot 5s 1 linear;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.35);
-moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.35);
box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.35);
}


 <div style='width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 110px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  top: 0px;
  left: 50%;'>
  <img class="smile" src='http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/4i9/5aX/4i95aXEiE.jpeg'/></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ablase/655UV/2/

If possible it would be better to use a simple transform like 'transform:rotate(170deg)', but when I try to achieve this the images themselves get rotated rather than staying right-side-up.

Using animation is okay I suppose but it seems to be impossible for the animation to persist in its end state, plus I'm guessing a simple transform might work in more browsers.

Thank you

Comment: I dont really get what you wanna to do :)

Comment: I want the small smiley image to rotate to a degree on the circumference of a circle.  The smiley image needs to stay right-side-up.  I want to do this without animation.  Just a regular non-moving transform if possible.  Basically if I replace this:

Comment: Basically if I replace this: 'animation: rot 3s 1 linear;' with this: 'transform:rotate(180deg);' all that happens is the smiley stays in center and rotates upside down...

Comment: Seriously I do really want to help you, I do. But Maybe I'm dumb I dont know but I dont get what u wanna achive. If you wanna rotate smiley nothing easier. Maybe do some visualisation I dont know..

Comment: @SzymonDziewoński Dziewoński thank you for your concern, somehow I solved it like this... http://jsfiddle.net/ablase/xJE6P/ The smiley was upside-down-so I used the opposite of the big circle's degree to turn it right-side-up!